# Import output from OPC UA-ModelCompiler into address space

Tags: c#, .net, opc, opc-ua

So I have successfully followed Stefan Profanter’s guide and created the model files using the UA-ModelCompiler. Goto [OPCUA.Rocks](https://opcua.rocks/custom-information-models/) for this awesome guide.

But how do I use these in .NET? I am using the OPC foundation .NET standard stack [.NET Standard](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard). I have got as far as the the CreateAddressSpace in the NodeManager but, I am struggling to find how to use the NodeSet2, uanodes, .xsd and other files produced by the ModelCompiler.

I have tried implementing the examples from [GitHub #546](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/546) below and do not get any errors. When I use the .Net stack Reference Client to browse the address space, I only see the the Server namespace. I was expecting to also see an animal namespace.

```
public override void CreateAddressSpace(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            IList<IReference> references = null;

            if (!externalReferences.TryGetValue(ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, out references))
            {
                externalReferences[ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder] = references = new List<IReference>();
            }

            string resourcepath = "C:\\Desktop\\UA-ModelCompiler-master\\Bin\\Release\\New\\animal.NodeSet2.xml";
            ImportXml(externalReferences, resourcepath);
        }
    }

    private void ImportXml(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences, string resourcepath)
    {
        try
        {

            NodeStateCollection predefinedNodes = new NodeStateCollection();

            Stream stream = new FileStream(resourcepath, FileMode.Open);
            Opc.Ua.Export.UANodeSet nodeSet = Opc.Ua.Export.UANodeSet.Read(stream);

            foreach (string namespaceUri in nodeSet.NamespaceUris)
            {
                SystemContext.NamespaceUris.GetIndexOrAppend(namespaceUri);
            }
            nodeSet.Import(SystemContext, predefinedNodes);

            for (int ii = 0; ii < predefinedNodes.Count; ii++)
            {
                AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, predefinedNodes[ii]);
            }
            // ensure the reverse refernces exist.
            AddReverseReferences(externalReferences);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing my guide. It may make sense to include a specific link so that others also know which guide you mean (there may be more in the future). In addition, please mention which specific .Net stack you mean.

Comment: What did you already try? Maybe this helps: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/546

Comment: @StefanProfanter I have updated my question based on you comments.

Comment: Ok, It's better now, but there is still information missing. So you tried to implement it, but what is the result of your test? Are there error messages? Why does this code not work? Which other things did you try? Include as much info as possible in your post

Comment: @StefanProfanter Thanks for your patience; I have added my final steps. I like to reverse engineer other people’s projects to understand it at a very basic level. A basic server with a model containing a single String data type would suit as a starter. The .Net quick starts are not that easy for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I know the samples from OPC Foundation are not easy, therefore I added a description how to add the own information model to a server, see [here](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/tree/master/Workshop/DataTypes#use-information-model).

This will work with any OPC UA Server using the [OPC Foundation NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua/).

Another example would be the [iot-edge-opc-plc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-opc-plc/blob/8e8f63374f265a8e300fe598420abbcdf7245929/src/PlcNodeManager.cs#L259) in integrates the own complex datatype [Boiler](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-opc-plc/tree/master/src/Boiler).